# how to make dpdk processes tolerable to segmantation fault?

Tags: c, error-handling, segmentation-fault, runtime-error, dpdk

In a normal c program, I saw that the segmentation fault in 1 loosely coupled thread doesn't necessarily affect other threads or the main program. There, I can check all the threads by process ID of it in every certain period of time and if some unexepected segmentation fault occurs or got killed I can re run the thread and it works fine. I can later monitor the logs and inspect the situation.

But I saw that, segmentation fault or other unexpected error in remotely launched (using DPDK) functions on different core affects the whole dpdk process and whole dpdk program crashes.. why is that?

Is there any alternative way to handle this scenario ? How can I take measures for unexpected future error occurance where I should auto rerun dpdk remote processes in live system ?

Comment: You solve it by actually fixing the issue, not by ignoring it.

Comment: my intention is not to ignore the issue, but not to disturb the live running system. We can always inspect the issue and build a new error-free version later.

Comment: Then use a monitor program which detects if the real program is running or not. If it's not running then the monitor program starts it.

Comment: I have a java app running which actually run my dpdk app and monitors it.. currently it detects whether the dpdk app is alive or not and run it again if not alive (maybe 1-3 second delay). What I wanted is, my dpdk app is consists of main processes and multiple secondary processes originated from main process on different cores. I thought it would be nicer to detect the liviliness of secondary processes from main process but saw that main process dies too when secondary processes get segmentation fault or something like that.